# Distributed Processing - AWS Sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I have a few raw `.csv` files in my S3 bucket. How can I process them in parallel to reduce run time? See comments on where I require a little help. I am using `SKLearnProcessor` and `s3_data_distribution_type='ShardedByS3Key'`

[image]

```
%%writefile preprocessing/preprocessing_sklearn.py
    
import pandas as pd
import argparse
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import os

def process(input_data_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(input_data_path)
#     drop first col (unamed: 0)
    df = df.iloc[: , 1:]
    
    features = df.iloc[:,1:]
    headers = features.columns
    labels = df.iloc[:,0]

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    
    normalized_x_train = scaler.fit_transform(features)

    # write
    pd.DataFrame(normalized_x_train).to_csv((os.path.join('/opt/ml/processing/output/train', 'train_features.csv')), header=False, index=False)
    pd.DataFrame(labels).to_csv((os.path.join('/opt/ml/processing/output/train', 'train_labels.csv')), header=False, index=False)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # HOW DO I MAKE THIS DYNAMIC?
    input_data_path = os.path.join("/opt/ml/processing/input", "train-data-with-header.csv")  
    process(input_data_path)
```

My calling fn -

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.processing import SKLearnProcessor
from sagemaker.processing import ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()
# WHAT SHOULD BE MY SOURCE?[![enter image description here][1]][1]
source = "s3://sagemaker-end-to-end/data_tuning/train/chunk_0.csv" 
source2 = "s3://sagemaker-end-to-end/data_tuning/train/"

sklearn_processor = SKLearnProcessor(framework_version='0.23-1',
                                     role=role,
                                     instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge',
                                     instance_count=2,
                                     base_job_name = 'preprocess-sklearn'
                                    )

sklearn_processor.run(
    code='preprocessing/preprocessing_sklearn.py',
    inputs=[
        ProcessingInput(
            source=source2,
            s3_data_distribution_type='ShardedByS3Key',
            destination='/opt/ml/processing/input')
    ],
    
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(
          source='/opt/ml/processing/output/train', 
          destination= make_url(store_bucket, "preprocess_sklearn", "train")
        ),
#                                
        ProcessingOutput(
            source='/opt/ml/processing/output/test',
            destination= make_url(store_bucket, "preprocess_sklearn", "test")
        )
    ]
                     
)

stop = timeit.default_timer()

print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

Answer (score 2):

When it is `specified s3_data_distribution_type='ShardedByS3Key'` and a s3 folder where our data is split into *n* files, Sagemaker will send to each processing instance a batch of files.

[image]

Each of these files can be accessed in the instance inside the path volume path (by default `/opt/ml/processing/input/`). Then we only need to list all the files in this path.

from pathlib import Path

```
for file in Path("/opt/ml/processing/input/").rglob('*.parquet'):
  file_path = str(file)
  # load file and process it.
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS documentation is not clear how they manage the horizontal scaling and aggregate the outputs from multiple instances into S3. I believe we can only assume the SageMaker looks after the parallel processing automatically with the `s3_data_distribution_type='ShardedByS3Key'`, splits the input data into shards, assigns each shard, and aggregates the outputs.

The only remarks I saw so far.

- [Data Processing with scikit-learn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/use-scikit-learn-processing-container.html)

> To **process data in parallel using Scikit-Learn** on Amazon SageMaker Processing, you can shard input objects by S3 key by setting `s3_data_distribution_type='ShardedByS3Key'` inside a ProcessingInput so that each instance receives about the same number of input objects.

- [S3DataDistributionType](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_ProcessingS3Input.html)

> Whether to distribute the data from Amazon S3 to all processing instances with FullyReplicated, or whether the data from Amazon S3 is shared by Amazon S3 key, **downloading one shard of data to each processing instance**.

By default. `S3DataType='S3Prefix'` and files under the S3 path specified are used.

- [S3DataType](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_ProcessingS3Input.html)

> Whether you use an S3Prefix or a ManifestFile for the data type. If you choose `S3Prefix`, **S3Uri identifies a key name prefix. Amazon SageMaker uses all objects with the specified key name prefix** for the processing job. If you choose ManifestFile, S3Uri identifies an object that is a manifest file containing a list of object keys that you want Amazon SageMaker to use for the processing job.

AWS github examples only uses one instance `instance_count=1`, hence cannot get the clue either.

- [Basic SageMaker Processing Script](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker_processing/basic_sagemaker_data_processing/basic_sagemaker_processing.ipynb)
- [Scikit-Learn Data Processing and Model Evaluation](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/sagemaker_processing/scikit_learn_data_processing_and_model_evaluation)

---

Only hope AWS will improve its documentation.

- [Why I think GCP is better than AWS](https://nandovillalba.medium.com/why-i-think-gcp-is-better-than-aws-ea78f9975bda)

> It’s not that AWS is harder to use than GCP, it’s that **it is needlessly hard**; a disjointed, sprawl of infrastructure primitives with poor cohesion between them.  
> A challenge is nice, a confusing mess is not, and **the problem with AWS is that a large part of your working hours will be spent untangling their documentation and weeding through features and products to find what you want**, rather than focusing on cool interesting challenges.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is very little official documentation around distributed "processing", found that `s3_data_distribution_type='ShardedByS3Key'` works along with some changes in the code that facilitates each of the sharded chunks of data to be fed to each instance running in parallel.
The process code could need to have a function is going to repeat on every instance in order to produce the output, and that function needs to be called within a loop which passes file names of each chunk as an argument.

Below is some sample code for reference :

```
%%writefile preprocess.py
import pandas as pd # used for handling the dataset
import boto3
import glob

    
def main_func(input_csv_file_path):
.....
some processing you need to do
.....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import boto3
#     os.system("pip install package_here") # add any system installs for packages you need

    #get a list of the input files that are copied onto the instance in the input folder
    print("The files we found were:")
    print("\n")
    files = glob.glob("/opt/ml/processing/input_data/*.parquet")
    print(files)
    # your total number of files will be input_files_number / instance_count
    for index, file in enumerate(files):
        
        #run our main function
        main_func(file)
        print("successfully procesed", file)
```

On the processor related code which actually triggers the job :

```
from sagemaker.processing import ScriptProcessor, ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

#name your job name
base_job_name='dev-name-testing'

script_processor = ScriptProcessor(command=['python3'],
                image_uri="763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/huggingface-pytorch-trcomp-training:1.9.0-transformers4.11.0-gpu-py38-cu111-ubuntu20.04",
                role=get_execution_role(),
                base_job_name=base_job_name,
#                 instance_type='ml.g4dn.xlarge',
                instance_type="ml.m5.large",
                instance_count=20)

script_processor.run(code='preprocess.py',
                    inputs=[ProcessingInput(
                        source='s3://bucket/users/name/input/',
                        destination='/opt/ml/processing/input_data',
                        s3_data_distribution_type='ShardedByS3Key',
                        s3_data_type='S3Prefix'),
                        ],
                    outputs=[ProcessingOutput(
                        source='/opt/ml/processing/processed_data',
                        destination='s3://bucket/users/name/output',
                        s3_upload_mode="EndOfJob")],
                    )
```

For more details, please refer [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/2852#issuecomment-1098298569).